# Is $\langle X^2Y + Y^2X \rangle$ a monomial ideal in $K[X,Y]$?

Tags: ideals, monomial-ideals

> Is $\langle X^2Y + Y^2X \rangle$ a monomial ideal in $K[X,Y]$ (where $K$ is a field)?

I have a feeling the answer is no, but I am having trouble justifying it.

Can anyone show me how to prove this?

I suppose that if this is indeed a monomial ideal, then every monomial in $X^2Y + Y^2X $ must be divisible by a monomial in our generating set. So every monomial in our generating set must be of degree $\leqslant 2$. Is this fact helpful in proving it?

Comment: In general, a principal ideal is monomial if and only if it is generated by a monomial (in which case any single generator of the ideal is a monomial).

Answer (score 2):

No. If it were, then $X^2Y$ and $XY^2$, being monomials within
the generator $X^2Y+XY^2$, would be in the ideal. They are not.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that every element in the ideal vanishes at $(-1,1)$, this is impossible for a monomial. Hence $$(X²Y+Y^2X)\subseteq K[X,Y]$$ is not a monomial ideal.